# Output Div Tag CSS Style Not Working

Tags: css, html, styles, stylesheet

Ok so here's what's happening.  Using the Moneypress LE plugin for Wordpress.  Am able to effectively output the html though file "CSL-products_class.php" for a buy now button with the Div Tag "buynow".  The problem is the style associated w/ it through my attached stylesheet will not load.

**You can see the problem by inspecting one of the products while looking at the source code live on my site at http://www.dustinschmidt.com.  The html is there but no style.**

Added the followng block of code:

```
$product_output[] = "<div class=\"{$this->css_prefix}-buynow\">";
        $product_output[] =
                "<a href=\"{$product->web_urls[0]}\" rel=nofollow target=\"cyber-    sprocket-labs\">".'</a>';
        $product_output[] = '</div>';
```

Here is what "CSL-products_class.php" now looks like.

```
<?php


class wpCSL_products__mpcj {


function __construct($params) {

    // Properties with default values
    //
    $this->columns = 1;                 // How many columns/row in our display output.

    foreach ($params as $name => $value) {
        $this->$name = $value;
    }
 }

/*-------------------------------------
 * method: display_products
 *
 * Legacy Panhandler stuff that will eventually come out.
 * This method generates the HTML that will be used to display
 * the product list in WordPress when it renders the page.
 *
 */
function display_products($products) {
    $product_output[] = '';
    $moneyFormat = get_option($this->prefix.'-money_format');
    $linkModifiers = get_option($this->prefix.'-link_modifiers');
    $currCol = 0;        
    foreach ($products as $product) {

        // If we are on the first column, start a new row div
        //
        if ($currCol == 0) {
            $product_output[] = '<div class="'.$this->css_prefix.'-row">';
        }

        $product_output[] = "<div class=\"{$this->css_prefix}-product\">";
        $product_output[] = "<h3>{$product->name}</h3>";
        $product_output[] = "<div class=\"{$this->css_prefix}-left\">";
        $product_output[] = "<a href=\"{$product->web_urls[0]}\" target=\"cyber-sprocket-labs\" $linkModifiers>";
        $product_output[] = "<img src=\"{$product->image_urls[0]}\" alt=\"{$product->name}\" title=\"{$product->name}\" />";
        $product_output[] = '</a><br/>';
        $product_output[] = '<div class="'.$this->css_prefix.'-zoombox">';
        $product_output[] = '<a class="thickbox" href="'.$product->image_urls[0].'">&nbsp;</a>';
        $product_output[] = '</div>';
        $product_output[] = '</div>';
        $product_output[] = '<div class="'.$this->css_prefix . '-right">';
        $product_output[] = '<p class="' . $this->css_prefix . '-desc" >'.$product->description.'</p>';
        $product_output[] = '<p class="' . $this->css_prefix . '-price">'.$product->currency;
        if (function_exists('money_format') &&  ($moneyFormat != '')) {
            $product_output[] =
                "$ <a href=\"{$product->web_urls[0]}\" rel=nofollow target=\"cyber-sprocket-labs\" $linkModifiers>".
                trim(money_format($moneyFormat, (float)$product->price)) .
                '</a>';
        } else {
            $product_output[] =
                "$ <a href=\"{$product->web_urls[0]}\" rel=nofollow target=\"cyber-sprocket-labs\">".
                trim(number_format((float)$product->price, 2)) .
                '</a>';
        }
        $product_output[] = '</p>';
        $product_output[] = "<div class=\"{$this->css_prefix}-buynow\">";
        $product_output[] =
                "<a href=\"{$product->web_urls[0]}\" rel=nofollow target=\"cyber-sprocket-labs\">".'</a>';
        $product_output[] = '</div>';

        $product_output[] = '</div>';
        $product_output[] = '<div class="'.$this->css_prefix.'-cleanup"></div>';            
        $product_output[] = '</div>';

        // Move to the next column, if we already hit the max desired
        // output columns, close the row and get ready for a new one
        //
        $currCol++;            
        if ($currCol == $this->columns) {
            $currCol = 0;
            $product_output[] = '</div>';
        }
    }

    // We did not end output on the last column
    // so we need to close the row div
    //
    if ($currCol > 0) {
        $currCol = 0;
        $product_output[] = '</div>';
    }

    return implode($product_output);
 }    


}
```

Finally my CSS for div tag "buynow".

```
.csl_themes-buynow{background:url("../../core/images/buy-now.png") no-repeat;width:175px;height:64px;float:left}
```

Thanks For Your Help,
Dusty

Comment: do all the other classes load fine?  for instance, does  "<div class=\"{$this->css_prefix}-product\">" load the right class?

Comment: yeah all of the other classes load up. This buynow class is the only custom class i'm trying to insert.  Looks like the stylesheet itself is not loading because i can't access it when i click on the link in <head>.  Hmm.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see by going to http://www.dustinschmidt.com/watches/ and viewing the source, the "csl_themes-buynow" class is reference on several divs.  For instance...

```
<div class="csl_themes-buynow"><a href="http://www.anrdoezrs.net/click-5462802-10535303?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.ashford.com%2Fashford%2Fbrowse%2FproductDetail.jsp%3FproductId%3D96B139%26source%3D406010001&cjsku=96B139" rel=nofollow target="cyber-sprocket-labs"></a></div>
```

So, it looks like something might not be setup correctly in your CSS.

Try just putting a loud border on that CSS (something like `border: 10px solid limegreen`) and see if it shows up...

Comment: Much thanks for taking a look at this Zack.  Tried adding the border and the CSS class is not even being acknowledged by my browser. Do you think i might have to register the CSS sufix "-buynow" within the plugin?  This stylesheet is not loading in <head> correctly and seems like it's probably the issue. <link rel='stylesheet' id='csl-mp-cjcss-css' href='http://www.dustinschmidt.com/wp-content/plugins/moneypress-commission-junction-le/css/csl-mp-cj.css?ver=7797' type='text/css' media='all'/>

Comment: I'm not sure...so, the ".csl_themes-buynow" is in it's own style sheet?  Do you have multiple stylesheets that are being used?  I would recommend trying to put ".csl_themes-buynow" into a stylesheet that you know is loading on the page.

Comment: Managed to figure it out. Total newbie relapse. CSS versioning was not updating new styles. Changed my CSS header to <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_url'); echo '?' . filemtime( get_stylesheet_directory() . '/style.css'); ?>" type="text/css" media="screen, projection" />

Comment: Glad to hear it.  You should post this comment as your answer and then mark it as the accepted answer when you're able to as it may help the next guy who comes along and has a similar problem...